# ASP.net post to server slow on big pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.net page using jquery 1.10.2 that generates a lot of data an sends it to the client.
When I submit the received clientpage back to the server (pressing submit) it takes a very long time to reach the server. (in chrome it says:uploading xx%)

I now clear the div where the data sits in (

> $('#datadiv').html('');

)
but, although it's empty before getting submitted, it still is on snail speed.

**Questions:**

*now that the div is empty what is it sending that takes that long?*

*How to make it faster (paging is not an option) ?*

Comment: Why is paging not an option? Did you disable viewstate? How much data are we talking? Are you sure it's the client side that slows? Could it be some sort of blocking call on the server? Is your server underpowered? There's a lot of information here that's important to know in order to receive a viable answer.

Comment: Paging: its generated in 1 select with commit/rollback;
DataSize: typically 200K-2.5MB
Clientside:I think its the datatransfer.
Server underpowerd: happens on localhost and on remote server

Comment: Viewstate: shouldn't that be small after cleaning the html in the div?

Comment: You should *disable* viewstate at the page or site level, then selectively enable it for controls that need it. That may dramatically decrease the size of the data being sent to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lopsider Well fiddler messed up my dev environment somewhat (vs2010 webserver) So as I thought viewstate only passes formfields I never tried mason's suggestion and disabeling it WORKED! So i've to do a bit more reading on the life an contents of viewstat. @Mason & @Yuriy Thnks!

Answer (score 2):

Div or other html-tags are not sended back to server at POST request.
You have to investigate the particular problem. Please install [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to debug the real POST request parameters.

I think that problem is in ViewState or other hidden fields.

Comment: @Ton I agree that Fiddler is the best recommendation here. Anytime you need to figure out when and what data is being sent to the server, defer to Fiddler. Also, if you don't mind posting your findings, I would be interested in reading them.